# What are the main uses of the LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know how to perform the procedure, but why is it useful?
The question is inspired by the eigenvalue decomposition, which is great for powering matrices.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for my answer is Richard C. Penney's *Linear Algebra: Ideas and Applications,* 4th edition.

*LU* decomposition is useful if you want to solve the matrix equation *AX = Y* for many different *Y*s with the same *A* because in that case, you need decompose *A* only once, and *AX = LUX = Y* can be solved without row reduction.

Another feature that makes *LU* decomposition numerically efficient is that as you reduce *A* to get *U*, you get *L* without any more work.